# Error Deserializing JSON in vb, Why am I getting Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid array passed in, ',' expected?

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization

I am new to using JSON with VB.net. I am trying to deserialize the following json.

```
{
"Polygon": [
    [
        "regionName": "North Coast",
        "coordinates": [
            [ -58209.320199999958277, 441960.463400000706315 ], 
            [ -58162.889899998903275, 441929.368699999526143 ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "regionName": "East Coast",
        "coordinates": [
            [ -58209.320199999958277, 441960.463400000706315 ], 
            [ -58162.889899998903275, 441929.368699999526143 ]
        ]
    ]
]}
```

However I am receiving an error, stating "Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid array passed in, ',' expected", when running the code on the deserializing line

```
Dim allRegions() As Polygon
Dim ser As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()

Public Function initialize() As Boolean
    allRegions = New Polygon(2) {}
    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "BLL\ShapeGisClasses\testing.json")
    Dim jsonString As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
    allRegions = ser.Deserialize(Of Polygon())(jsonString)

    Return True
End Function
```

For reference my Polygon class is

```
Public Class Polygon
     Public Property regionName As String
     Public Property coordinates() As Coordinate
End Class
```

And the coordinate class is a similar class with lat,lon properites. Most the the examples and tutorials I'm seeing online have a different JSON structure so it's hard to compare. Any insight on where i'm going wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual JSON? The internal square brackets should be braces, IMO (you have properties there). As in `{ "Polygon": [ {  object1a }, { object1b } ] }`. Anyway, the root is a JObject that defines an array of Polygon, not a JArray. Also, don't pre-declare the array to a specific dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jimi's advice, I adjusting my JSON to be

```
{
"regions": [
    {
        "regionName": "North Coast",
        "coordinates": [
            [ -58209.320199999958277, 441960.463400000706315 ],
            [ -58162.889899998903275, 441929.368699999526143 ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "regionName": "East Coast",
        "coordinates": [
            [ -58209.320199999958277, 441960.463400000706315 ],
            [ -58162.889899998903275, 441929.368699999526143 ]
        ]
    }
]}
```

Fixed my problem.